# JUnit test case error: "Address already in use: bind"

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, junit

I have a JUnit test case for my Project which is developed using
SpringBoot (1.3.5) & JDK 8. When I run my project as JUnit test in STS, all
test cases pass, but gives error at the end of each test cases, which
is: I am trying to run JUnit Coverage:

```
ERROR [ main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:182) - |||||||||Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:773)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986)
    ........
    ........
    ........
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
ERROR [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:182) - |||||||||Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
```

This error shows as the port 8080 is already in use. How to avoid this
error and let my all 20 test cases to run in one flow without this
error?

> My code is:--->

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(KYCNotificationApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@WebIntegrationTest
@IntegrationTest({"server.port=0"})
public class DetermineKYCNotificationServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    DetermineKYCNotificationServiceImpl kycService;

    @Mock
    KYCOperationsDao kycOperationsDao;

    @Mock
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
         ...
    }

    @Test
    public void testMeth1() {
        try {
             .....
            assertTrue(......);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testMeth2() {
        try {
             .....
            assertTrue(......);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> ...2o more test cases....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring Boot < 1.4 you can annotate your test class with `@IntegrationTest({"server.port=0"})`

In Spring Boot >= 1.4 you can use `@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class , webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`.

Both approaches have the same effect, namely; Spring will assign a random port (and will magically update the application properties in your test context to reflect this test-specific port).

More details [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) ...

> If you need to start a full running server for tests, we recommend that you use random ports. If you use `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` an available port will be picked at random each time your test runs.
>
> The `@LocalServerPort` annotation can be used to inject the actual port used into your test. For convenience, tests that need to make REST calls to the started server can additionally `@Autowire` a `TestRestTemplate` which will resolve relative links to the running server.

**Update 1**: based on your updated question I can now see that you are using @WebIntegrationTest. In this case you could simply add the `randomPort` parameter to that annotation e.g.

```
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
```

Comment: I am still facing the issue same port is in use issue while running JUnit code coverage in STS. Please suggest.

Comment: In your test case you are using **both** `@WebIntegrationTest` and `@IntegrationTest`. These annotations are not intended to be used _together_. Generally, you would use either `@IntegrationTest({"server.port=0"})` **or** `@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)` Rather than adding annotations without - perhaps - fully understanding what they do I would strongly recommend reading the docs to which I linked in my answer and understanding what Spring is doing in this case.

Comment: Hi glitch -Thank you for your prompt response , the issue solved with your following suggestion:       @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(KYCNotificationApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)